# Shelosha Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Gershon's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6540/shelosha-asar-umatayim-mi-yodeya/6549#6549):

The gematria of the names סיחון עוג is equal to that of כוזו במוכסז כוזו - both 213. The connection: we write these names on the outside of the mezuzah to prevent evil forces (kelipah) from entering the house. Conversely, these two kings were like an "anti-mezuzah" preventing the forces of good (the Jews) from entering Eretz Yisrael, and so they had to be removed first.

([Bnei Yissaschar, partly from Megaleh Amukos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14490&pgnum=339))

Comment: I've always heard the _sefer_ called _B'ne Yisaschar_, with the second _sin_ pronounced. Is your _m'sora_ different, R'Alex?

Comment: I guess you're right - it's just that I'm used to pronouncing the name without the second sin in all other cases.

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4290/silent-letter-in-yisachar

Comment: And also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6545/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-inscription-on-the-back-of-a-mzuza

Comment: And re the comments, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10750.

Answer (score 2):

כוזו במוכסז כוזו = 213 the words that are written on the back of a Mezuza by the Ashkenazim.

It is also the Gematria of 'וידעו כי אני ה

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assyrian_captivity_of_Israel), there were 213 years from the beginning of the reign of [Ashur-dan II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_Assyria#Middle_Assyrian_Period) over Assyria until the capture of *Shom'ron*.

Comment: Weak, I know, but I couldn't find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

According to Strong's concordance, there are 213 *p'sukim* in *Tanach* in which the word *תורה* (in its sense of "law" or similar) and 213 in which the word *מועד* (in its sense of "appointment" or similar) appears. (I have no Jewish source for either of these claims.)