# How to pronounce the name of the sefer "Bnei Yso(s)cher"

Tags: names, books-generally, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation

How does one pronounce the name of the sefer בני יששכר ?

I've heard people pronounce both sins -- so it is Ysoscher. (There is also a common custom to pronounce the name יששכר with both sins the first time it appears in the Torah, and thereafter with only one sin.) But recently I heard someone pronounce the sefer Ysocher, with only one sin, the way it is usually pronounced in the Torah. So which is correct?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/silent-letter-in-yisachar

Comment: Customs vary on pronouncing the name in Torah. In addition to the one you cite of pronouncing it one way on its first appearance and a different way on later appearances, there are customs to pronounce both sins every time or to pronounce one sin every time.  Since the author of the book is from a Chassidic community, and it first gained popularity there, and those are communities where the 2 sin pronunciation is more common, that seems to be the pronunciation that spread for the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this excerpt of a letter](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/lkus/30/14/5/287) (published in the Hosafot of Likutei Sichot volume 30, Parshat Vayeitzei) from the Lubavitcher Rebbe, written Rosh Chodesh Tammuz 1981, may be addressing this issue.

If I understand it correctly, The Rebbe is responding to someone who wrote to him about something the Rebbe said about Yissachar vs Yisshasschar.

The Rebbe clarifies that he wasn't discussing that halachic ramifications, or how we read it in the Torah. Those issues are discussed in other places. Rather he was pointing out the inherent contradiction in the way people pronounce the name of Seferim (everybody pronounces both letters) and the way people pronounce the name (pronouncing only one letter).

It's a little hard for me to be 100% certain that this is what the Rebbe is writing, since I don't have any context (maybe someone can clarify it), but it seems from here that the Rebbe is saying that people pronounce the sefer with both "sins".

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex: If you think that's a problem, consider upvoting and sharing this: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/why-not-automatically-archive-links-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: @Alex I updated the link

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Yaakov Moshe Hilel Shelit"a pronounced it "Bnei Yisoschor."